# Boot Camp Windows 10 partition size capped on macOS Catalina

Tags: windows, catalina, bootcamp

I'm trying to install Windows 10 on my MBP 13 mid 2012 using Boot Camp Assistant. I've been clearing up free space on my HD and when I thought I have enough (500GB disk with currently ~240GB free space) I can't seem to get more than ~85GB of dedicated space for a Windows partition. To make things even more weird, every time I re-run the Boot Camp Assistant I'm getting less and less space. Is that space being reserved by Boot Camp Assistant and not getting released after? Does anyone know how I can release it myself?

I ran `diskutil apfs resizeContainer disk0s2 limits` to check the limits and this is what I got:

[image: diskutil apfs resizeContainer disk0s2 limits]

And this is how the disk space looks from Disk Utility:
[image: Disk Utility 1]
[image: Disk Utility 2]

My goal is to dedicate ~150GB of the disk for Windows 10 installation but can't seem to make it happen.

Thanks for the help

Comment: What does `tmutil listlocalsnapshots /` show?

Comment: @DavidAnderson it says: `Snapshots for volume group containing disk /:`